# javascript web console with undefined variable and uncomplete loop

Tags: javascript, console

Browser: `Firefox 70.1`
Not getting loop output in console with following code;

```
for (var x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
  print(window.x);
}
```

Prints only "9", and not whole loop, in output pane.

```
for (var x = 5; x < 10; x++) {   
  console.log(window.x); 
}
```

Prints `undefined`.

But when `alert` is used instead of print and console.log, everything works fine.

Comment: Is that code inside a function, by any chance?

Comment: `print(1); print(2);` also only prints `2`. `console.log(window.x);` works fine in global scope. Note that `print` is a special function only available in the console. It’s one of the [helper functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers), although it’s not documented. `pprint` behaves the same.

Comment: Are you intending to call `window.print`? Guess not, I wonder what the `print` function actually is

Comment: @Amadan No function used, Code written as it is, in console pane.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Not at this moment. Currently just trying to print loop in output pane. After reading few pages on Google and SO came to know about window.variable _name, and print option, hence tried them, but still can't figure out, why it's not working.

Comment: In console, the second snippet logs `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, then prints `undefined` as the value of the snippet itself. I cannot reproduce your behaviour. I've never seen `print` (as opposed to `window.print`), but it seems to return a string representation of its first argument. Best not to rely on it.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. Due to your answer, I started checking settings, instead of code under console tab. There I found out, that output was getting generated but, it was hidden, as Logs option was not checked. Once it was checked output was visible.

Comment: @msinfo Seems you found the answer; it might be nice to write it up as an _answer_, not as a footnote to the question (and also accept it as correct, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you run 2nd block of the above code in the **browser**. It prints 5,6,7,8,9. Because In the browser, When **Global Execution Context** is created and you have `this` and `window` object available for you and `this === window` prints `true`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        console.log(this === window);
        for (var x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
            console.log(window.x);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All this is true, just not relevant to the question. Node was never mentioned, and the question was why the OP snippets did not log.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for pointing it out. I am removing it. I ran the code in the firefox console (70.1). It's working fine. I am thinking if you run the above code in the empty js file and execute it in Node, it prints undefined. Maybe this would be the scenario

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with code, but it was settings option in Console tab which made output non visible (or was limited to one line). Once Logs and info option were checked, output was visible properly. All thanks to @Amadan, who motivated to check settings instead of code.